# Is there a way to add a descriptive Assert message in a Boolean ZIO Test

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

I have a couple of `Booleans` I want to test, like

```
assert(g8Exists, equalTo(true)) &&
assert(projectExists, equalTo(true)) &&
assert(testenvExists, equalTo(true)) ...
```

If one fails, all I get is:

```
false did not satisfy equalTo(true)
```

No clue which line failed. Is there a way I can add a descriptive Assert message. For example:

```
assert(g8Exists, equalTo(true), "g8Exists")
```

Or preferred:

```
assertTrue(g8Exists, "g8Exists")
```

Would result in

```
false did not satisfy equalTo(true) - g8Exists
```

Or is there a better way to test `Booleans` in general?

Comment: How about creating an ADT instead of using booleans?

Comment: @MarioGalic thanks will do:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! You can use the `label` method on `Assertion` or its symbolic alias `??` for this.

```scala
assert(g8Exists, isTrue ?? "g8Exists") &&
assert(projectExists, isTrue ?? "projectExists") &&
assert(testenvExists, isTrue ?? "testenvExists")
```

Assuming that the first assertion fails you would get a nice error message indicating exactly which assertion failed.

```
false did not satisfy isTrue()
false did not satisfy (isTrue() ?? "g8Exists")
```

Comment: @adam-fraser - and as always there is already a nice solution - thanks;)